# How to filter from an array with objects in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregate

I have a collection in mongoDB with documents like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("some_id"),
    "name" : "name",
    "field1" : 123,
    "field2" : 234,
    "arr" : [ 
        {
            
            "a_num" : 3,
            "a1" : [ 
                { "f1": "000"},
                { "f1": "120"},
                { "f1": "012"}
            ],
            "a2" : {}
        }, 
        {
            
            "a_num" : 36,
            "a1" : [ 
                { "f1": "120"},
                { "f1": "012"}
            ],
            "a2" : {
                "f1": "011"
            }
        }, 
        {
            
            "a_num" : 34,
            "a1" : [],
            "a2" : {
                "f1": "000"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

While I'm using `aggregate()`
I don't want to get the `arr` elements where `a1` has an element, that its `f1` value is `"000"`, or where `a2` has `f1` that its value is `"000"`.
E.g, for the above document, I'd like to get:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("some_id"),
    "name" : "name",
    "field1" : 123,
    "field2" : 234,
    "arr" : [  
        {
            
            "a_num" : 36,
            "a1" : [ 
                { "f1": "120"},
                { "f1": "012"}
            ],
            "a2" : {
                "f1": "011"
            }
        } 
    ]
}
```

Any idea how?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Work with `$filter` operator.

1.1. `$not` - Negate the result of *1.1.1*.

1.1.1. `$or` - Match any conditions: *1.1.1.1* or *1.1.1.2*.

1.1.1.1. `$in` - Check "000" is in the `a1.f1` array of current iterate document.

1.1.1.2. `$eq` - Check the value of `a2.f1` field in the current iterate document is equal to "000".

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      arr: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$arr",
          cond: {
            $not: {
              $or: [
                {
                  $in: [
                    "000",
                    "$$this.a1.f1"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$this.a2.f1",
                    "000"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/guQqKqLU3wb)

---

Note:

```
$in: [
  "000",
  "$$this.a1.f1"
]
```

may equivalent to

```
$in: [
  {
    "f1": "000"
  },
  "$$this.a1"
]
```

if the **`a1` document contains only `f1` field**.